# Java count program (up or down)

Tags: java

So my object-oriented programming class have started this semester, and I want do well as I really enjoy programming. I'm having some issues with switching from Python to Java, which might be obvious if you look at my code. Could anyone help me with what's wrong ? When running my professors test-run code I get this error: "When reaching the end value, the count method should return false"
I don't see why the count method doesn't return false?

```
package stateandbehavior;

public class UpOrDownCounter {

private int counter;
private int end;

public UpOrDownCounter(int start, int end) {
    this.counter = start;
    this.end = end;
    if (start == end) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Start and end can't be the same.");

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
}
public boolean count() {
    if (counter < end) {
        counter ++; return true;
    }

    else if (counter > end) {
        counter --; return true;
    }

    else{
        return false;}
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UpOrDownCounter [counter=" + counter + ", end=" + end + "]";
}

}
```

TEST CODE PROVIDED BY THE PROFESSOR FOR CALLING MAIN()

```
package stateandbehavior;

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import no.hal.jex.runtime.JExercise;

@JExercise(
    tests="", // We don't want to test this element as a whole, since we 
can test the parts.
    description="A class that counts from a start value up or down to an end value. " +
            "The counting is constrained by the values provided to constructor and performed by the count() method."
)
public class UpOrDownCounterTest extends TestCase {

@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
}

private void testCount(UpOrDownCounter counter, int end, int delta) {
    boolean result = true;
    while (delta > 0 ? counter.getCounter() < end : counter.getCounter() > end) {
        assertTrue("Before reaching the end value, the count() method should return true. ", result);
        int i = counter.getCounter();
        result = counter.count();
        int expected = i + delta;
        assertEquals("When counting from " + i + " the result should be " + expected + ". ", expected, counter.getCounter());
    }
    assertFalse("When reaching the end value, the count method should return false. ", result);
    assertEquals("After reaching the end value, the counter should not change. ", end, counter.getCounter());
    assertFalse("After reaching the end value, the count() method should return false. ", counter.count());
    assertEquals("After reaching the end value, the counter should not change. ", end, counter.getCounter());
}

@JExercise(
        tests="UpOrDownCounter(int,int)",
        description="A constructor that initializes the UpOrDownCounter class with the provided start and end value. " +
                "After initialization the counter should be the start value. "
)
public void testUpOrDownCounter() {
    UpOrDownCounter counter13 = new UpOrDownCounter(1, 3);
    assertEquals("After instantiating an UpOrDownCounter the counter should be the start value. ", 1, counter13.getCounter());
    UpOrDownCounter counter31 = new UpOrDownCounter(3, 1);
    assertEquals("After instantiating an UpOrDownCounter the counter should be the start value. ", 3, counter31.getCounter());
}
//  @JExercise(
//          tests="UpOrDownCounter(int,int)",
//          description="A constructor that initializes the UpOrDownCounter 
class with the provided start and end value. " +
//                  "If the start and end values are equal, an 
IllegalArgumentException should be thrown. "
//          )
//  public void testUpOrDownCounterWithException() {
//      Exception iae = null;
//      try {
//          new UpOrDownCounter(0, 0);
//          fail("When the start and end values are equal an 
IllegalArgumentException should be thrown. ");
//      } catch (Exception e) {
//          iae = e;
//      }
//      assertTrue("When the start and end values are equal an 
IllegalArgumentException should be thrown, ", iae instanceof 
IllegalArgumentException);
//  }

@JExercise(
        tests="boolean count()",
        description="A method that steps the counter, unless it has reached the end value. " +
                "The method returns true as long as the counter has not reached the end value, and false otherwise. " +
                "This test checks that it properly steps upwards, when the end value is larger than the start value."
)
public void testCountUp() {
    UpOrDownCounter counter13 = new UpOrDownCounter(1, 3);
    testCount(counter13, 3, 1);
}
@JExercise(
        tests="boolean count()",
        description="A method that steps the counter, unless it has reached the end value. " +
                "The method returns true as long as the counter has not reached the end value, and false otherwise. " +
                "This test checks that it properly steps downwards, when the end value is smaller than the start value."
        )
public void testCountDown() {
    UpOrDownCounter counter31 = new UpOrDownCounter(3, 1);
    testCount(counter31, 1, -1);
}
}
```

Comment: `count()` is never called. The given "error" is not an error but probably a comment from your professor

Comment: Your `main` method doesn't do anything, so none of your code ever runs.

Comment: What should I put in the main method?

Comment: How is this code being called? Is it being called by a unit test or something?

Comment: @JayAddy: The `main()` method is the entry point for the application.  It would contain the top-level logic of whatever you want the application to do.

Comment: The counter should also work for start values greater than the end value. Thus as long as it is still counting (downwards in the situation you mentioned) it should still return True. It should only return False when done.

Comment: Yes. We download a jar file that calls every function we write. The code I provided can't be ran on it's own. But if it passes the "test-file" I get to move on to another project.

Comment: This error message seems incorrect (or at least misleading) to me. The logic of counting up or down depending on what the values are looks fine to me. The bigger question is how this is being called and exactly what the `main` method is supposed to contain. If this is literally just supposed to be a library function that's called from other code then you may not need a `main` method at all.

Comment: @JayAddy: Then effectively that "test file" is a stand-in for your `main()` method.  We don't know what that file is doing, how it's invoking this code, what expectations it has for the results, etc.  Can you examine the code in that file?  Can you run it in a debugger and step through the runtime behavior to observe specifically what's failing?

Comment: I've provided the calling-code. Please have a look.